# Maximum number of inserts per transaction on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, mosel

Does anyone know how many `INSERT` commands per transaction SQL Server can handle at the same time? Basically, I'm building a long string with bunch of `INSERT`'s (around 8000 `INSERT` commands, and each has around 600 characters) which then I will execute using a function `SQLexcute(sql_text)`:

```
for(obj in objects) {
    sql_text += "INSERT(prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4, prop5) VALUES(" + obj.prop1 + "," + obj.prop2 + "," + obj.prop3 + "," + obj.prop4 + "," + obj.prop5+");"
}
SQLexcute(sql_text)
```

Comment: I'm presuming you're using c# on the backend to generate the query text, if I'm correct, you should really be using a stringbuilder as opposed to concatenating the string like that, as every time you're adding something to a string, it's creating a new instance of the string (strings in c# are immutable).  As far as the SQL query, inserting 8000 records at a shot really shouldn't be that big of a deal.  I'm also presuming that you're cleaning the data for the object properties prior to generating the SQL query, as to disallow SQL injection?

Comment: The one thing to keep in mind is that SQL Server will **escalate** its locks to a **table-level exclusive lock** if you insert more than 5000 rows at once (in a single transaction) - so that table will be **exlusively locked** until that `INSERT` transaction commits - no other operations (not even `SELECT`) will be possible on that table in the mean time

Comment: Please please *please* use parameters rather than munging together strings (use `SqlParameter`s on a `SqlCommand` if this is C#): http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection

P.S. You are missing the table name in your query text

Comment: I'm not building on C#. i'm building the string on a different program. The programming language is Mosel

Comment: Regardless of the language the correct way to do this is with parameterized queries. In your case you might want to look at table valued parameters. It would perform much faster than 8k individual insert statements.

Comment: @SeanLange, Do you have a simple example on how it can be parameterized the queries?

Comment: I don't know anything about mosel so I can't help you with the syntax but surely any site that has examples of this language will have some examples. If not that, the documentation should. I would probably move this to a stored procedure and receive a table valued parameter with the 8k rows you want inserted

Comment: @SeanLange TVP probably won't work if the only interface is ODBC: https://www.msi-jp.com/xpress/learning/square/%28B%29Modeling%20and%20problem_Summary.pdf (start at page 101).

Comment: Ugh that stinks. Regardless it should be able to handle parameterized queries. Even passing in a massive string of values and splitting it would seem better performance wise than 8,000 individual inserts.

Comment: @SeanLange, parameterized sql queries worked. since i'm using odbc driver, i had to increase the buffer size too.

Comment: Awesome. Not only is your code much safer it is probably faster too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sean is right.

Do not execute the code in mosel. You have to create your query in T-SQL and pass the parameters there.

Here you have the link for table valued param:

[Tabled valued param](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Comment: TVP probably won't work if the only interface is ODBC: https://www.msi-jp.com/xpress/learning/square/%28B%29Modeling%20and%20problem_Summary.pdf (start at page 101).